# In MVP should my presenter provide views to its view?

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, mvp

I'm just learning how to use MVP and I want to make sure that I'm "doing it right".

I have main view with an associated presenter. This main view is composed of a few sub-components, at least one of which can be interchanged. So I turned these sub-components into their own view/presenter pairs.

The way I currently have my project setup is that main view/presenter launches off the project. When the main presenter is instantiated it makes calls to factory functions that create the other view/presenter pairs. The presenter then passes a reference to each of the other views to the main view where they are then added.

This way seems to make more sense to me, but I wanted to make sure I was on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the `Presenter` is a separate class than the `View`, so they are modular and the `Presenter` can be unit tested by itself (although I've rarely felt the need to in practice).

To build a window, I use a `WindowPresenter` containing a `WindowView` that

- builds and does the window layout with all the `Views`
- wires all the `Views` with their `Presenters` and `Models` (if they have one)

Usually, I just pass the `Model` and `View` into the `Presenter`'s constructor, although I have heard other people use dependency injection frameworks.

In sum, it sounds like you are doing it right except usually the `Presenter` and `View` are separate classes.  There are many ways to wire together the MVP triplets, typically I think this is done from the top-level `Presenter` class, but do whatever makes the most sense.